# I have a listener in my progam which I guess is wrongfully used

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have a response listener in my program and I got feedback about it like it is wongfully used.

```
val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
                        Method.POST,
                        url,
                        sendOrder,
                        Response.Listener {
                            
                            val response = it.getJSONObject("data")
                            val success = response.getBoolean("success")
                            val LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY = 1
                            if (success) {
                                val intent = Intent(this, PaymentActivity::class.java)
                                intent.putExtra("total_amount",totalAmount)
                               
                                startActivityForResult(intent,LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY)

                            } else {
@@ -116,7 +118,7 @@ class CartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
                            cartProgressLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        },
```

This is the feedback I got, what does it mean and how to change that ?

> Always have handling for unexpected responses like different keys or
> values or JSON structure or empty response

Comment: That means, it is possible to get a reponse that has no "data" or "success", and getJSONObject will throw exceptions. What do you want your app to do in such case? crash?

Comment: No, How should I handle it then ?

Comment: You can use retrofit instead of that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce exception handling, so that if recevied `JSON` doesn't satisfy the given structure your app doens't crash

```
try{
    val response = it.getJSONObject("data")          // This line can throw exception, if not handled it can cause your app to crash
    val success = response.getBoolean("success")     // This can also throw exception
    val LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY = 1
    if (success) {
        val intent = Intent(this, PaymentActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("total_amount",totalAmount)
        startActivityForResult(intent,LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY)
    }
}
catch(jsonException: JSONException){
    // Json parsing failed, notify user if required
}
catch(e: Exception){
    // Something else failed, notify user if required
}
```

Comment: catch (e: JSONException) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Some unexpected error occurred!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
I already have this catch.

Comment: I dont see it in the code that you posted

Comment: Is there any exception, if I get no response, diff Json structure, different key ???